# Black Scholes PDE vs closed form

Tags: options, black-scholes

What is the difference between the 2 formulas below, how and why we choose what to use? Does PDE simulate option price through time, therefore we can use it for American options as well?

Black Scholes PDE:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black%E2%80%93Scholes_equation

$[\frac{\partial V}{\partial t} + rS\frac{\partial V}{\partial S} + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2S^2\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S^2} - rV = 0]$

Black Scholes closed form
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black%E2%80%93Scholes_model

$$
C(S, t) = S_0 N(d_1) - X e^{-r(T-t)} N(d_2)
$$

d_1 = \frac{\ln\left(\frac{S_0}{X}\right) + \left(r + \frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)(T-t)}{\sigma \sqrt{T-t}}

d_2 = d_1 - \sigma \sqrt{T-t}

Chat gpt explanation:

> Partial Differential Equation (PDE):
>
> Advantages:
>
> - Flexibility: The PDE formulation is more flexible and can be extended to handle a broader range of option types, including American
>   options, options with early exercise features, and options on various
>   underlying assets.
> - Numerical Methods: The PDE can be solved numerically, allowing for the valuation of a wider range of financial derivatives beyond
>   standard European options.
>
> Limitations:
>
> - Computational Intensity: Solving the PDE numerically can be computationally intensive, especially for complex derivative
>   instruments. It may require more computational resources compared to
>   using the closed-form formula.

Comment: I personally used the closed form once, because I find it easier. The PDE allows you to better understand the derivation in my opinion.

Comment: Using PDE you can't get the value of your option by doing application of the functions to arguments you may have available (like volatility, strike and spot prices). Closed form expression allow you to do that: you will get the number which is the value of the option.
PDE is used to derive closed-form expression. It is possible for European options only. Other way to use PDE is to solve it numerically using some algo like finite differrences.